# Complex sort of a list of dicts by key: ascending and descending for every tuple of key's value

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I have a list of dicts that I want to sort by its 'segment'-keys, which are lists of tuples:

```
example = [{'segment': [(329, 363), (379, 397)], 'name': '1'},
           {'segment': [(329, 336), (339, 341), (396, 399)], 'name': '2'},
           {'segment': [(329, 363), (379, 399)], 'name': '3'},
           {'segment': [(329, 336), (337, 357), (396, 399)], 'name': '4'}]
```

The sorted list should look like this:

```
sorted_example = [{'segment': [(329, 363), (379, 399)], 'name': '3'},
                  {'segment': [(329, 336), (337, 357), (396, 399)], 'name': '4'},
                  {'segment': [(329, 336), (339, 341), (396, 399)], 'name': '2'},
                  {'segment': [(329, 363), (379, 397)], 'name': '1'}]
```

My desired output is sorted in a way, that I can easily check if dict[n+1] is fully contained in dict[n].

So first I want to sort ascending by the first element of the first tuple and then descending by the second element of the last tuple.
That's ok for cases like dict 1 and 3, but for other dicts like 2 and 4 I have to iterate over all tuples and sort ascending by its first element and descending by its second.

My code for achieving the first step is:

```
sorted_example = sorted(example, key=lambda k: (k['segment'][0][0], -k['segment'][-1][1]))
```

But I can't figure out how to iterate over all tuples in one list and sort them ascending and descending as described above.

I'd be very, very happy if someone could give me a hint!

Comment: I do not still get the sorting logic. Why is dict 3 the first in the sorted list while dict1 the last?

Comment: and what makes dict 4 to come before dict2?

Comment: My first sorting step looks at the first element of the first tuple and sorts them ascending. Since all values here are the same there's no problem with that. Next the dicts are sorted in descending order by the second element of the last tuple, so the 397 of dict 1 makes the dict the last element, because every other second element of last tuples is greater than 397.

Comment: In my second step this sorting logic applies to every tuple of each list: So the 363 of the first tuple makes dict 3 the first dict (descending order for second tuple elements!), while the first element of the second tuple of dict 4 is lower than the first element of the second tuple of dict 2 (337 < 339) (ascending order for first tuple elements!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generator expression that iterates over the tuples of a given sub-list in the dict, and returns a tuple of items with the second item negated so that it's sorted in descending order. Unpack the generator expression into the outputting tuple of the key function so that it's considered after the items placed for your first rule:

```
sorted(example, key=lambda k: (k['segment'][0][0], -k['segment'][-1][1], *((a, -b) for a, b in k['segment'])))
```

This returns:

```
[{'segment': [(329, 363), (379, 399)], 'name': '3'},
 {'segment': [(329, 336), (337, 357), (396, 399)], 'name': '4'},
 {'segment': [(329, 336), (339, 341), (396, 399)], 'name': '2'},
 {'segment': [(329, 363), (379, 397)], 'name': '1'}]
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! I had only a vague idea of generator expressions before. This will simplyfie some other code of mine too!

Comment: What would be the right syntax if I want to sort the dicts only by the generator expression? (without the `k['segment'][0][0], -k['segment'][-1][1]`) I tried many variations, but still get only syntax errors...

Comment: You can pass the generator expression to the tuple constructor instead in that case: `sorted(example, key=lambda k: tuple((a, -b) for a, b in k['segment']))`